# Delete lines in a file

Tags: python, file

I have this code that brute forces a parameter:

```
import urllib
import sys

with open('finaltext.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        site = urllib.urlopen("localhost/?cin="+line)
    if site.read() == "good":
        print line
        reponse = open("result.txt",'w')
        reponse.write(line)
        reponse.close()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print line+"NOO"
```

I want to make the code delete every line already bruteforced in the file `finaltext.txt,`so if I stop the process I can continue later from where I had stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib
import sys
s = open('index.txt','r')
indx = int(s.readlines()[0])
s.close()
with open('finaltext.txt', 'r') as f:
    g = open('result.txt','w')
    finaltext = f.readlines()
    for line in finaltext[indx:len(finaltext)]:
        indx+=1
        with open('index.txt','w') as ixfile:
            ixfile.write(str(indx))
        site = urllib.urlopen("localhost/?cin="+line)
        if site.read() == "good":
            print line
            g.write(line)
        else:
            print line+"NOO"
    g.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Untested. I also don't think this is really right because I have no idea how any of your stuff actually works.

EDIT: How about this?

Comment: this code only print the good line but if the process will take so long and the finaltext file is huge how can i delete every line tested so if i stop the code i can continue from where I had stopped.

Comment: Create a counter, and write it to a file each iteration.  When you restart, read the counter file to find out which line you are on

Comment: If the file is huge it is not advisable to do it like this. Reading all lines at once & opening and closing again & resetting your f-pointer takes a lot of ram. How about rewriting it so that you write which items you have done and then XORing it. I think a better solution actually would be keeping an index of where you are and if you stop the process, the index gets written. That  means you don't need to save much

Comment: @Mustapha Mouzaki Something like this?

Comment: @MustaphaMouzaki Sorry forgot to save. Try this. Also make sure there's a file in your directory called index.txt with 0 on the line.